# How to solve FTP 550 error "access is deny" because bad connection while uploading

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

How to solve FTP 550 error "access is deny" because bad connection while uploading.
I'm sure that my server already give permission because sometimes I can upload without problem.
I'd read some post say that this happen because server had got slow connection but I want to know is there someone can solve this problem

here is my code :

```
public bool FTPUploadFunct(string uploadto2, string newskinlocation2)
    {
        bool FTPUploadFunct = true;
        MethodInvoker methodInvokerDelegate = delegate()
        { toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Uploading...."; };
        this.Invoke(methodInvokerDelegate);
        try
        {
            //delete old file
            FtpWebRequest requestFileDelete = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadto2);
            requestFileDelete.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("FTPUser20", "1234");
            requestFileDelete.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

            FtpWebResponse responseFileDelete = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDelete.GetResponse();

            //upload new file
            FtpWebRequest requestFTPUploader = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadto2);
            requestFTPUploader.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("FTPUser20", "1234");
            requestFTPUploader.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(newskinlocation2);
            FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

            int bufferLength = 2048;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

            Stream uploadStream = requestFTPUploader.GetRequestStream();
            int contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

            while (contentLength != 0)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(contentLength / fileInfo.Length));
                uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
                contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }

            uploadStream.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);

            requestFTPUploader = null;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            FTPUploadFunct = false;
            String status = ((FtpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription;
            MessageBox.Show(status + "error while in FTPUploadFunc");
            errorNumber = (int)((FtpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;
            if (errorNumber == 550)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("550" + "error while in FTPUploadFunc2");
            };
        }
        return FTPUploadFunct;
    }
```

for many time it stuck at

```
requestFileDelete.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
```

but sometime at

```
requestFTPUploader.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found 90% success rate.
and wait before upload new file for about 3.5 sec

```
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3500);
Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```